# How do I refresh a connection every 20 seconds?

Tags: java, url, connection

I wish to refresh an open connection every 20 seconds as a webpage updates

How do I add to the code below to refresh the connection?

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL oracle = new URL("https://news.google.co.uk/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
           System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you ask 'the world' to read your code, please indent it properly

Comment: You need to check the T&C for the service that you are polling.  If you poll once every 20 seconds for long enough, someone is going to notice ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). Wrap the task in a class, as follows:

### NewsTask.java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class NewsTask implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    URL oracle = new URL("https://news.google.co.uk/");
    URLConnection yc = oracle.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
       System.out.println(inputLine);
    in.close();
  }
}
```

Then, have the task run like this:

### URLConnectionReader.java

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    NewsTask task = new NewsTask();

    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0L, 20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) could be what you looking for. You just need to wrap your logic in a `Runnable` an submit it to the `executor`.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->{
... your task
}, 0L, 20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Or  declare a `Runnable` explicitly if you aren't using Java 8.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
 void run(){
   .. your code
 }
};

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0L, 20L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Hi Sleiman, i am fairly new to Java so im not clear what you mean by wrapping the logic in a runnable?

Comment: Can i follow this example? http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=54

Comment: @MrAssistance yes you can, it does something similar, plz check my updated answer. It should be easier to understand.